# missing nmea messages on Oreo

Tags: android, gps, nmea

On Android 8 devices nmea strings often don't get send to the OnNmeaMessageListener. While at the same time the LocationListener does get Location updates (using GPS_PROVIDER).

On Android 7.1 and before the same code gets nmea messages every second.

My service is in the foreground, so it can't be the new energy saving stuff.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It seems to be a problem specific to the sony xperia f5321. With a samsung g930f everything works as expected.